# Kendo UI Remote DataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

This is with reference to a question posted on the Kendo UI DataSource forum by a colleague of mine. I'm cross posting it here to try to get a solution.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/failure-to-read-remote-datasource

We are trying out [this simple Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OpupU) using a remote URL to populate the datasource (open console to see the ouput). While modifying this to use one of our data URLs (and using `json` as the datatype), it doesn't work. Its an internal URL, so its not accessible from SO but I'll post the request/response headers, and the data seen using Chrome's Developer tools. The data source is making the request to the URL and getting a response, but nothing happens after that.

Response data

```
[{"tradeVolume": "33454327",
  "numberOfTrades": "130498",
  "tradeSizeStdDev": 13048.15096724034,
  "quoteSizeStdDev": 1306.394869511115,
  "medianTrade": 100.0,
  "eightiethTradeSize": 200.0,
  "ninetiethTradeSize": 334.2000000000029,
  "ninetyFifthTradeSize": 334.2000000000029,
  "ninetyEighthTradeSize": 1100.0,
  "ninetyNinthTradeSize": 2000.0,
  "medianQuoteSize": 1000.0,
  "eightiethQuoteSize": 1550.0,
  "ninetiethQuoteSize": 2050.0,
  "ninetyFifthQuoteSize": 2050.0,
  "ninetyEighthQuoteSize": 4300.0,
  "ninetyNinthQuoteSize": 5600.0,
  "ninetyNinthFiveQuoteSize": 7850.0
}]
```

Request/Response Headers

[image: Headers]
[image: Response]

Can't figure out why the datasource doesn't like the response. If we use the same response as a local datasource, it works, so I don't think there is an issue with the format of the JSON.
Also, any pointers on best ways to debug such issues would be very helpful to us.

UPDATE: This is an updated Dojo example that shows the code we have been trying. We have removed the URL since its an internal once, but the request/response headers are the ones seen above.
http://dojo.telerik.com/@juliayu/apEHA

Comment: Image links are broken.

Comment: Also, try to post your entire kendo widget source code, so we can try figure out what is happening. The *dojo's*  code is using `jsonp`, are you sure this is right for your case??? The response doesn't seems to be a jsonp response at all.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Why do you say that? I can open them without any issues.

Comment: I'm saying that because I get `Error 521: Server is down` on both links you've provided. Probably a CloudFlare problem.. can you attach it directly on SO post(you have enough rep I think), or even imgur ?

Comment: That's weird. I'm able to open it even on my mobile connection. I'll post the images directly. But I think I figured the problem. Its not correctly formulated as a `jsonp` response.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I've tried the dojo example internally (so datatype does not need to be jsonp) and it still does not work. I've updated the question with the request/response headers and linked to a new dojo that shows the code we are running internally.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you have defined the property `data` of your schema as `Item`, so I think the dataSource will look for a property with that name in the data, like if your data was `{ Item: [{ ... }] }`. Did you tried: 1- removing this property; 2- addind an object `Item` with you data as value in your respose to fit that pattern?